# Can you identify the set for this transparent and printed orange canopy, with number 56?

Tags: set-identification

[image]

Part from unknown set. Can someone please help to identify the set number?

Answer (score 5):

This is from set [4587-1: Duel Racers](https://brickset.com/sets/4587-1/Duel-Racers)

[image]

Comment: @Tom Awesome that you've found the set. Please accept this answer to show others this question has been resolved.